# how to create a function in python that gives elements of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

I have an array. Let's say a=array([[10, 2, 13, 55]])
I want to create a function that gives me the 1st element for t=0, the second element for t=1...

I have tried the following:

```
def a(t):
    return a[t]
```

Comment: Here's a hint: is `a` the name of your array, or the name of your function?

Comment: My version of `python` doesn't understand your example data: `a=array([[10, 2, 13, 55]])`.

Comment: I dont understand your question. You simply access your array by `a[0][t]`

Comment: from numpy import array

Comment: Ok, edited tags to include `numpy`

Comment: Do you understand the dimensions of   your array?  multidimensional indexing in numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```py
a=array([[10, 2, 13, 55]]) 

def get_value(t):
    return a[t]

get_value(0) #results [10, 2, 13, 55]
```

Since your example data is 2D , if we want to access each of them we must pass 2 numbers as index.

```py
a=array([[10, 2, 13, 55]]) 

def get_value(t1,t2):
    return a[t1][t2]

get_value(0, 1) #results 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This function, only works if you have arrays of the shape [[...]], otherwise, you have to change the level parameter.

```
from numpy import array
a=array([[10, 2, 13, 55]])
def matrix_reader(a,t,level=0):
    return a[level][t]
matrix_reader(a,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is 2D array so you need 2 parameter to return the correct number that you want.
Example: With your array `a=array([[10, 2, 13, 55]])`, `a[0,0]` return 10, `a[0,1]` return 2.

I recommend you create 1D array, put your array into function and named your function different from your array

```
from numpy import array
temp=array([10, 2, 13, 55])
def a(arr,t):
    return arr[t]
print(a(temp, 2))
```

The example return 13